# JMeter HashTree not sorted correct after loading project in JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I do have a har file that I need to parse with JMeter StandardJMeterEngine...
and produce a jmx file.

I'm creating the TestPlan, threadGroup, loopController and for each page a TransactionController.
After loading the file in JMeter, the elements are not in the correct order.
I expect them to appear in the order parsed and added in the threadGroup HashTree.

Parsing them in the following order:

```
page_6 
page_7 
page_8 
page_9 
page_10 
page_11 
page_12 
page_13 
page_14
```

Finally, I get this in JMeter:

[image]

Any ideas?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [HashTree JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/collections/HashTree.html) it derives from [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and the Map doesn't preserve insertion order hence your "expectation" is wrong.

The easiest way of converting a .har file into JMeter test script is using [BlazeMeter Converter](https://converter.blazemeter.com/)

Comment: Yes, you are right.
But due to sensitive data I cannot upload my har file, I have to implement something "in house"